# ASP.Net Linq to Entities: Web Config connection string when used 3-tier architecture

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-entities, web-config, 3-tier

I have been having intermittent trouble with data access so I'm rebuilding my project.  I have a 3-tiere architecture using Linq to Entities with my App_Data folder with my database in by DATA (DL) layer.  The only connection string to the data is in the Data layer (DL) web.config.

I am getting a error message in my UI in the **'var GetFeatured'** statement that states that "The type 'DL.RESTAURANT' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'DL."  I have a reference in the UI to the Business Logic layer and the Business Logic layer has a reference to DL.  What am I missing?

**USER INTERFACE CODE-BEHIND**

```
BLgetFeatured obj2 = new BLgetFeatured();
            int one = 29;
            int two = 54;
            int three = 49;
            int four = 41;

            int restID = one;
            var GetFeatured = obj2.getFeatured(restID);

   var GetFeatured = obj2.getFeatured(restID);
    litRestName.Text = GetFeatured[0].REST_NAME;
    litRestStreet.Text = GetFeatured[0].REST_STREET1;
    litRestPhone.Text = GetFeatured[0].REST_PHONE;
    litRestCity.Text = GetFeatured[0].CITY.CITY_NAME;
    litRestCuisine.Text = GetFeatured[0].CUISINE.CUISINE_NAME;
    litRestShortDesc.Text = GetFeatured[0].REST_DESC;
    restImage.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + GetFeatured[0].REST_IMAGE;
```

**BUSINESS LOGIC LAYER**

```
using DL;

namespace BL
{
    public class BLgetRestaurants
    {

    public List<RESTAURANT> getRestaurants(string cuisineName, string cityName, string priceName, string ratingName)
    {
        DLgetRestaurants obj = new DLgetRestaurants();
        var restaurantList = obj.getRestaurants(cuisineName, cityName, priceName, ratingName);
        return restaurantList;
    }
  }
}
```

**Data Layer (DL)**

```
namespace DL 
{
  public class DLgetFeatured
  {
    FCGuide db = new FCGuide();
    public List<RESTAURANT> getFeatured(int restID)
    {
        var restList = (from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs.Include("CUISINE").Include("CITY")
                        where RESTAURANT.REST_ID == restID
                        select RESTAURANT).ToList();

        var result = (from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs.Include("CITY").Include("CUISINE")
                      where RESTAURANT.CUISINE.CUISINE_ID == RESTAURANT.CUISINE_ID
                      && RESTAURANT.CITY.CITY_ID == RESTAURANT.CITY_ID
                      orderby RESTAURANT.REST_NAME ascending
                      select RESTAURANT).ToList();

        return restList;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You realize that you're directly querying your DAL from the UI and not actually using the business layer class.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt think so.  BLgetFeatured obj2 = new BLgetFeatured();
            int one = 29;
            int two = 54;
            int three = 49;
            int four = 41;

            int restID = one;
            var GetFeatured = obj2.getFeatured(restID);

Comment: Take a look at the code above (I have added in more of my code to the UI)and I am believe with the BLgetFeatured obj2 = new BLgetFeatured(), that is going to my BL layer.  Is that not correct?

Comment: tvanfosson- do you have a moment to look at my comments?  I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: You must not have included the relevant code.  I don't see a getFeatured method or BLgetFeatured class.  Regardless, you're using a  RESTAURANT object that exists in the DL and that requires you to include the DL as a reference so it understands the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference to DL in your UI project.  Since you are using that type in the UI project, you need a reference to it.

Comment: Does that cause a problem for a 3-tier architechture when I trying to keep my data access separate from the UI?  I kinda thought I understood that from my ASP.Net class ...???